# How can i set a limit to the number of results given in cloudkit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, icloud, cloudkit

Here is my code for retrieving data from icloud. How do i limit the number of data it retrieves to 25? I saw this question answered before, but i'm not sure how to apply it to my code? can you help?

Here is where i saw the question answered before. Please tell me exactly how to add it to my code or just give an answer with it in the code.

[CKQuery from private zone returns only first 100 CKRecords from in CloudKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592964/ckquery-from-private-zone-returns-only-first-100-ckrecords-from-in-cloudkit)

[CloudKit Batch Fetches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27134258/cloudkit-batch-fetches/27135836#27135836)

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var EventsArray:[String] = [String]()

    var container:CKContainer?
    var privateDatabase:CKDatabase?
    var publicDatabase:CKDatabase?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        self.privateDatabase = self.container?.privateCloudDatabase
        self.publicDatabase = self.container?.publicCloudDatabase


        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self

        self.LoadEvents()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func LoadEvents() {

            let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
            let query:CKQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "Data", predicate: predicate)
            query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

            if let database = self.publicDatabase {
                database.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: { (records:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) in

                    if error != nil {
                      self.alert("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)", Message: "Make sure iCloud is turned on and you are connected to the internet")
                      self.loading.hidden = true
                    }
                    else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                            self.EventsArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                            for record in records {
                                let usernameRecord:CKRecord = record as CKRecord
                                if let event = usernameRecord.objectForKey("Events") as? String{
                                    self.EventsArray.insert(event, atIndex: 0)
                                }
                            }

                            //update data
                            self.collectionView.reloadData()
                            self.loading.hidden = true
                        }
                    }
                    })
                }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performQuery you should use a CKQueryOperation.
Then you can set the result limit like this:

```
operation.resultsLimit = 25
```

In this question you can see how to use a CKQueryOperation: [CKQuery from private zone returns only first 100 CKRecords from in CloudKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29592964/ckquery-from-private-zone-returns-only-first-100-ckrecords-from-in-cloudkit)